# MS Access VBA changing TextBox filled by a ComboBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

i got a question about some "simple" MS Access vba. I got a ComboBox. When an item is selected, various TextBoxes are updated. Now i want to edit the text that is put in a TextBox after an item is selected (Because the data is filled with a very much spaces, so i want them out).

I tryed "before update", "after update", "on dirty" and "on change" events, but none of them seems to be the right one.. Anyone knows what i'm looking for? Thanks

Comment: I added a breakpoint in the events on the first rule, but it is not getting in either one of the events. And this: `SQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo_Recept_Gegevens8C WHERE Receptnr = '" & Combo0.Value & "'"
    Form.RecordSource = SQL` is how the TextBoxes are filled by the ComboBox (Thats working fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways:

(1) Instead of just entering the field name for each text box's `ControlSource` property, enter an expression, e.g. `=Replace([SomeField], " ", "")`. This assumes the text boxes are supposed to be read-only.

(2) Don't use data binding at all, and instead set each text box's `Value` property explicitly:

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(SQL)
txtWhatever.Value = Replace(RS!SomeField, " ", "")
txtAnother.Value = Replace(RS!AnotherField, " ", "")
```

In the second case updating the data source with any altered values will need to be handled explicitly too.

That said, if the data has unnecessary spaces, surely they should be cleaned up at source, rather than as the data is put into the UI...?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I'll try out your options, i'll let you know. The problem with the data is that it is entered over the past 10 years and somehow (don't even know how) every record contains about 150 words, with loads of spaces between every word. Considering there are about 1000 records, it's going to take wayyyyy to much time. Then is left to mention that it is only to show (read) the data, nothing happens with that part of the data ever again than  reading in this specefic TextBox:)

Comment: Without any trouble your first solution worked fine. Thanks a lot!